# Removing cost when radio-button is selected, Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button, e-commerce

I´m learning ruby on rails by creating a Ecommerce app.

My problem is how would I remove the `delivery cost` if the customer has either selected  `Pick up in store` or the total amount is higher than `$100`?

So when the `Pick up in store` or when total amount is grater than `$100` the delivery cost should be removed.

I've used `if` and `else` to get the desired result. But by using that the `Total cost` is not updating when the `radio buttons` are selected.

This is the code with out the `if`and `else`

```
    <tr>
            <th><p>Products Total: </p></th>
            <th><p>Delivery Cost: </p></th>
            <th><p>Total Cost: </p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p ><%= @cart.total_price_usd %></p></td>
      <td><p ><%= @del_cost_usd %> </p></td>
      <td><p ><%= @cart.total_price_usd + @del_cost_usd%></p></td>   
    </tr>

    <div>   
      <li><%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "1", checked: false, class: 'delivery-options', data: { question: "Pick up items in store" }  %> 
      <%= f.label :pick_up, "Pick up items in store" %></li>

     <li><%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "0",  checked: true, class: 'delivery-options' , data: { question: "Have items sent by mail" } %> 
     <%= f.label :pick_up, "Have items sent by mail", class: ''  %></li> 
    </div>
```

Can someone inform me on the results I want.

This is probably easy points for the one with the experience

TIA 
Codegirl

Comment: Someone will probably be able to answer directly. I'm not as fluent to give you a 'off the top of my head' answer but look up 'hiding elements using JavaScript'. I use it in some of my apps for the same purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a plan to solve that.

Give the DOMs you show label and value of Delivery Cost a class to toggle their display attribute:

```
<p class="delivery-cost-fields">Delivery Cost: </p>
<p class="delivery-cost-fields"><%= @del_cost_usd %> </p>
```

For your 'Pick up items in store' radio button, define it's 'onchange' like below:

```
<%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "1", checked: false, class: 'delivery-options', data: { question: "Pick up items in store" }, onchange: "$('.delivery-cost-fields').toggleClass('hidden', true)"  %>
```

For your 'Have items sent by mail' radio button, define it's 'onchange' like below:

```
<%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "0",  checked: true, class: 'delivery-options' , data: { question: "Have items sent by mail" }, onchange: "$('.delivery-cost-fields').toggleClass('hidden', false)" %>
```

Define a hidden css class:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I like this. I'm curious to see if it works. Nice and low key.

Comment: @Nhã Huỳnh,  This is working except for the line `      <td><p ><%= @del_cost_usd %> </p></td>` the `id="delivery-cost"` doesn't seem to have any affect on this line.  Why is that? and what do I have to do to make it disappear?

Comment: @codegirl I just fixed my answer. We should toggle the display attribute of both the description p tag and the value p tag of the Delivery Cost. Prev I just make the description tag disappear. :D

Comment: @Nhã Huỳnh, thank you, Both fields are disappearing now.  But the delivery cost is  still adding to the  `total cost`  as in this line `<td><p ><%= @cart.total_price_usd + @del_cost_usd%></p></td>   `  is it possible to make it not add the `total_price_usd` to `del_cost_usd` when the pick up in store is selected?

Comment: I think it can be solved from your backend, or you should use something like local calculating or ajax to solve this one. :D

Comment: @Nhã Huỳnh, well I guess I have to take a deep look into that since I have so little experience on the backend stuff :)